# How to use pattern replace in elasticsearch to replace "— " with "–"

Tags: elasticsearch, replace, sense

Some of my documents includes "—" em dash and I would like to replace it with "–" en dash. From what I read in elasticsearch https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html, I can use a pattern replace which uses a regular expression.

Something like this:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "my_char_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "my_char_filter": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "(\\d+)-(?=\\d)",
          "replacement": "$1_"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What should I specify in pattern and replacement? Or is there any other way to replace  "—" em dash with "–" en dash in elasticsearch other then pattern match in all the documents. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pattern replace char filter is a correct choice but I'm not pretty sure about standard tokenizer because it’s remove “-“ sign. If you execute GET /_analyze {   "analyzer": "standard",  "text": "--------------" } then you will get nothing. What exactly are you trying to do? Provide example input string and an information about tokens you want to have.